# Find several words in a string in r

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have a column where the values are semicolon (;) separated. For example, values in the column could be:

I will not always have the same number of elements being separated.

```
string1="abacavir sulfate; lamivudine; zidovudine"
string2="omeprazole magnesium; amoxicillin ; rifabutin"
string3="acetyl chloride; calcium"
```

I need to put them into a regex so I can see which strings in my other dataframe has all the words in there:

```
string_1_regex="^(?=.*\\babacavir sulfate\\b)(?=.*\\blamivudine\\b)(?=.*\\bzidovudine\\b)"
string_2_regex="^(?=.*\\bomeprazole magnesium\\b)(?=.*\\bamoxicillin\\b)(?=.*\\brifabutin\\b)"
string_3_regex="^(?=.*\\bacetyl chloride\\b)(?=.*\\bcalcium\\b)"
```

Comment: What is your question? Are you looking for a generalized function?

Comment: Depending on how large your data is, regex may be slow. You might be better off separating out each word into a vector/list (computationally cheap) and then doing a join between the datasets. If your solution works fast enough for you then ignore this comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option with `str_replace`

```
library(stringr)
str_c("^", str_remove_all(str_replace_all(str_remove_all(c(string1, 
    string2, string3), "(?<=;)\\s*|\\s*(?=;)"),
     "\\s*(?<=^|;)\\s*([^;]+)", function(x) sprintf("(?=.*\\%s\\b)", x)), ";"))
```

-output

```
[1] "^(?=.*\\abacavir sulfate\\b)(?=.*\\lamivudine\\b)(?=.*\\zidovudine\\b)"    
[2] "^(?=.*\\omeprazole magnesium\\b)(?=.*\\amoxicillin\\b)(?=.*\\rifabutin\\b)"
[3] "^(?=.*\\acetyl chloride\\b)(?=.*\\calcium\\b)"
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that you are looking for a function that will achieve this in a generalized way.

Here is my approach to define such a function:

```
library(magrittr)

regexify <- \(s) strsplit(s, ";") %>%
                   unlist() %>%
                   trimws() %>%
                   sprintf("(?=.*\\%s\\b)", .) %>%
                   c("^", .) %>%
                   paste(collapse = "")
```

With this you can do

```
Map(regexify, list(string1,
                   string2,
                   string2))
```

returning

```
[[1]]
[1] "^(?=.*\\abacavir sulfate\\b)(?=.*\\lamivudine\\b)(?=.*\\zidovudine\\b)"

[[2]]
[1] "^(?=.*\\omeprazole magnesium\\b)(?=.*\\amoxicillin\\b)(?=.*\\rifabutin\\b)"

[[3]]
[1] "^(?=.*\\omeprazole magnesium\\b)(?=.*\\amoxicillin\\b)(?=.*\\rifabutin\\b)"
```